# Show that the set is unbounded

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be given in the standard basis by the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}3 & 2 & 4 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 4 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Find a unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^tTU=\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal.

I have done this and found that $$\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix} 8 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now let $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $f(x)=x\cdot T(x)$ be a quadratic form.

Argue that the set $$\{x:f(x)=1\}$$ is unbounded.

Suppose $x=Uy.$ Then this gives $$x\cdot Tx= Uy\cdot TUy=y\cdot(U^tTU)y=y\cdot\Lambda y=8y_1^2-y_2^2-y_3^2$$

Where do I go next?

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Try the set $S = \{ (t+\frac{1}{\sqrt8},t\sqrt{8},\sqrt{2t\sqrt{8}} ), t \in \mathbb{R}, t>0 \}$. For $s \in S$, what is $f(s)$? What is $\max\{|s|, s \in S\}$?

Comment: Could you expand on this?

Comment: I found it by starting with $8y_1^2 = stuff + 1$ and choosing $y_2^2$ and $y_3^2$ so that they delete the stuff. This set is unbounded ($\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} ||s(t)||=+\infty $ ). Which point do you want me to expand?

Comment: Could you explain exactly how to found the set $S$?